# Extra vertical space between aligned equations in ConTeXt?

Tags: spacing, equations, context

In LaTeX, I can use `\\[3mm]` for example, to put extra vertical space, if I think it will improve the readability of displayed, aligned equations.  And in fact I find I do this quite a bit.  But what is the ConTeXt equivalent to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ConTeXt does not have an interface for increasing the interline space. You would have to add the space manually. For example:

```
\startformula \startalign
  \NC a \EQ b + c \NR
  \noalign{\blank[2cm]}
  \NC a \EQ b + c \NR
\stopalign \stopformula
```

If you want, you can add an interface for it. I did not test it too thoroughly.

```
\unprotected\def\doalignNR[#1][#2]%
  {\donestedformulanumber{#1}{#2}\crcr
    \noalign{\mathalignmentparameter\c!inbetween}}
```

Then you can use:

```
\definemathalignment[loosealign][inbetween={\blank[2cm]}]

\starttext

\startformula \startloosealign
  \NC a \EQ b + c \NR
  \NC a \EQ b + c \NR
\stoploosealign \stopformula
```

Comment: Thank you very much: the `\noalign{\blank[2cm]}` does exactly what I want.

Comment: @Alasdair: Since you seem happy with this answer, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count. This shows that answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).